# IP provided by metallb is not accessible

Tags: kubernetes, metallb

I have a bare-metal Kubernetes cluster with metal LB.
I have used a GCP external Load balancer for an IP that I have assigned to Metallb.
Metallb has assigned that IP to service but still I am not able to access my service on that IP from outside Cluster.

```
   apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: nginxlb
        spec:
          type: LoadBalancer
          selector:
            app: nginx
          ports:
          - name: http
            port: 80
            targetPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
    
    
    
  apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx
      replicas: 2
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: nginx
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx:latest
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
    
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      namespace: metallb-system
      name: config
    data:
      config: |
        address-pools:
        - name: default
          protocol: layer2
          addresses:
          - 34.149.177.23-34.149.177.23
```

Comment: You need to provide more info like Metallb config and your service YAML file.

Comment: @yip102011 I have included my deployment , svc , metallb configuration file. 
IP used in metallb address is IP of my GCP Load balancer

Comment: Did you find any solution ?
I am having same issue here